# Padding a String to a Fixed Column Width

Tags: delphi, padding

I've figured out one method, but is there a better way to do this?

I need to print multiple lines containing 6 columns to a text document. The columns are 20 characters wide. The information placed in each column contains an unknown number of characters. I need to pad the right side of the string with spaces until it's 20 characters long.

```
procedure TRunTimeCalculatorMain.LoadPrinter();
var
i, blankcount, columnwidth: integer;
addspace, nam, min, ave, max, tot, cal : string;
begin
  columnwidth := 20;
  for i := 0 to Classes.ListofStuff.Count -1 do
  begin
      nam := Classes.ListofStuff[i].itemtype;
      min := Format('%1.5e', [floattostr(Classes.ListofStuff[i].minimumtime)]);

      blankcount := columnwidth - Length(nam);
      addspace := StringofChar(' ', blankcount);
      nam := nam+addspace;

      blankcount := columnwidth - Length(min);
      addspace := StringofChar(' ', blankcount);
      min := min+addspace;

      LoadPrinterList.Add(nam+min);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Are you aware of [`TStringHelper.PadLeft`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.PadLeft) and [`TStringHelper.PadRight`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.PadRight)?

Comment: You could leave the formatting to another 'format' command. `min := Format('%-20s', [min]);`  the negative will left-align as desired, in a 20 char field.